# Using django-endless-pagination with a custom c-based view that extends ListView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-endless-pagination

Reading [django-endless-pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)'s Docs it says that you can extend it's [Ajax](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html#a-shortcut-for-ajaxed-views) paging functionality to class-based views just by using the @page_template() decorator...
I've been trying to implement that decorator for like an hour using:

```
class ExtendedListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'global_template.html'

    @method_decorator(@page_template('path_to_updatable_content_only_template'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ExtendedListView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The view functions doesn't output any errors but when i go to another page it loads the 'global_template' in the target and not the template defined in the decorator.

If anyone knows if this implementation actually works and i'm making some mistake please point it out, i'll be glad to use it the right way.

I've managed to come up with a workarround so if someoene's got this same problem and there's no compliant answer to this you can do this:

```
class ExtendedListView(ListView):
    template_name='global_template_path'

    ''' 
    render_to_response ¿hack? so that i can render only the updatable DOM part template
    '''
    def render_to_response(self, context):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            self.template_name = 'path_to_updatable_content_only_template'
            return super(ExtendedListView, self).render_to_response(context)
        else:
            return super(ExtendedListView, self).render_to_response(context)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Officially, you can use the AjaxListView to do this task:

```
# views.py
from endless_pagination.views import AjaxListView    
class BookView(AjaxListView):
    context_object_name = "books"
    model = Book

    template_name = 'books.html'
    page_template = 'books_list.html'
```

in book.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/endless.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 

<div class="endless_page_template">

    {% include page_template %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

and this is books_list.html

```
{% load endless %}

{% paginate books %}

{% for book in books %} 
    {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">

    {% show_pages %}
</div>
```

Comment: My problem with that is trying to get multiple pagination to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite convoluted how the Ajax implementation works.  I had to roll my own solution because I wanted to use generic views, Ajax, and multiple pagination.  To figure out how to make it work, I had to reverse engineer the code from the examples, the django-endless-pagination decorators, and Django's views themselves.  In the process of rolling my own solution, I simplified things a bit, but it could probably be simplified even further.  Perhaps this might be of use to someone else:

```
class SearchView(View):
    """
    Based on code from django-endless-pagination, modified for multiple
    pagination views on the same page 
    """

    template = 'app/search.html'
    page_templates = {'object1Page': 'app/search_object1_pane.html',
    'object2Page': 'app/search_object2_pane.html'}

    def get_context_data_and_template(self, **kwargs):
        context = {'params': kwargs}

        # Check whether AJAX has made a request, if so, querystring_key will be
        # set, identifying which paginator to render
        querystringKey = self.request.REQUEST.get('querystring_key')
        template = self.page_templates.get(querystringKey)
        # switch template on ajax requests
        if not (self.request.is_ajax() and template):
            template = self.template    
        context['page_template'] = template

        # Always generate the QuerySets that will be paginated
        if self.request.GET['query']:
            searchTerm = self.request.GET['query']
        else:
            searchTerm = kwargs['search']

        # *** Insert your search code here ***   

        context['object1Results'] = object1QuerySet
        context['object2Results'] = object2QuerySet

        extraContext = self.kwargs.get("extra_context", {})
        context.update(extraContext)

        return context, template

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context, template = self.get_context_data_and_template(**kwargs)
        return TemplateResponse(request=self.request,
            template=template,
            context=context)
```